# static files from subdomain, fcgi from root

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to send requests for

```
foo.com -> foo.com/dispatch.fcgi
```

and requests for a subdomain

```
bar.foo.com -> foo.com/bar
```

I have this in my .htaccess file;

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# if request matches this (NC - make all req lower case)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bar\.foo\.com$ [NC]
# then redirect here
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://foo.com/bar/$1

# if request isn't to the bar URI
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/bar/ [NC]
# and it isn't a file name (? guessing here)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

with this my `fcgi` script is working fine, but every attempt to access `bar.foo.com` results in a 302 response

```
302 Found

The document has moved here (http://bar.foo.com).
```

I'm pretty sure that it's my `ReWriteRule` for `bar.foo.com` that's mucking things up, but I can't work out how to fix it (and preserve the fcgi route).

Answer (score 0):

If a request was made to `http://bar.foo.com` it was being setn to dispatch fcgi. I added a `RewriteCond` to check for this instance and everything started working. Maybe this will be useful to someone, one day... !

```
# if request matches this (NC - make all req lower case)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bar\.foo\.com [NC]
# then redirect here to subdomain
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /bar/$1 [L]

# if request isn't to the bar URI
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/bar/ [NC]
# and the HOST request isn't bar.foo.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^bar.foo.com [NC]
# and it isn't a file name (? guessing here)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# send it to the fcgi
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```